# How can I count the keys inside a for each loop?

Tags: php

```
    function findKey($array, $keySearch) {
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
            if (stripos($key, $keySearch) !== false){
            $count++;
            echo "<li>".$key."</li>";
                }
            if (is_array($item)){
               findKey($item, $keySearch); 
            }
        } 
        echo "Total number of keys: ".$count;       
    }

echo findKey($array, $keySearch);
```

I try to count the keys inside my for each loop. But my result is

banana

apple

orange

Total number of keys: 0010101000

What did I do wrong?

Comment: its recursive function. your count is everytime will be 0 or 1 :)

Comment: See the first statement of `findKey()` function. In each call to the function the variable `$count` will be set to 0. Make it `global` or `static`

Comment: your approach seems to be redundant. Want the simpler and optimized one? Show the input array and key to search

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Oh why? :´(

Comment: @Jarla, "Show the input array and key to search"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   function findKey($array, $keySearch) {
        global $count;
        foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
            if (stripos($key, $keySearch) !== false){
            $count++;
            echo "<li>".$key."</li>";
                }
            if (is_array($item)){
               findKey($item, $keySearch); 
            }
        } 
    }

$count = 0;
findKey($array, $keySearch);
echo "Total number of keys: ".$count;
```

Comment: Oh, I understand! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Do you know, why people downvoted my question? :´( Is it a bad question?

Comment: by the way echo before calling findKey will result in nothing, because function does not return anything

Comment: About downvoiting - i think because it contains  too simple errors which you should debug yourself

Comment: One more question, it is totally fine when you do not answer it, I am still trying to figure it out! I am just wondering how it is possible to call the total number of keys before the results of findKey. Right now it seems impossible to me

Comment: no way. you should scan the array to count the keys

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!